# Can I dynamically generate parameters in Azure templates?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

AFAIK, all the parameters have to be defined in the parent template right from the start. Is it possible to generate parameters dynamically at all, such as looping n times to generate n name fields?

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates#parameters) shows how parameters are defined in templates. Note that none of the parameters are created dynamically.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking - can you give some detail of the problem you're trying to solve with the approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameters that depend on parameters to emulate something like that:

```
"parameters": {
    "first": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "lol"
    },
    "second": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[concat('not_so_', parameters('first'))]"
    }
}
```

would give you value of `not_so_lol` for the `first` parameter.

You another option is to create variables that take values depending on the parameter:

```
"parameterOne": "defaultValue": x, - I'm lazy to type out proper definition in json.
...
"option-x": "something"
"option-y": "something-else"
"result": "[variables(concat('option-', parameters('parameterOne')))]"
```

so this is basically an `If` statement in ARM template. the value of the `result` variable equals to `"[variables('option-x')]"` or `"[variables('option-y')]"`, depending on your input.

Another (a bit more complex option) is to use deployments outputs. So an example would be, you create a deployment filled with different outputs needed by you (basically you create a pool of constants), and after that, you can reference that deployment outputs in all of your templates (given they reside in the same subscription, but you can create that deployment in all of the subscriptions). that would basically create a pool of constants you can get needed value based on the current value.

```
"something": "[reference(concat('resourceGroupName', 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/', parameters('deploymentName')),'2015-01-01').outputs]",
```

The last (most complex) option is to construct needed stuff on the fly, using nested templates. That's a bit too much to get through in an answer, but I'll just say that in this case you need to use nested templates as aggregator\transformator, where you feed values in and get desired output. This is pretty advanced stuff, but worth knowing. [This](https://github.com/4c74356b41/armotron/blob/master/ml-vm-ml-dd.json) would be a good example (for starters).

Answer (score -1):

According to your description, we can use `uniqueString()` to achieve generate parameters dynamically. This function is helpful when you need to create a unique name for a resource.

More information about [uniqueString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-string#uniquestring), please refer to this link.

Comment: Sorry, I might not have worded my question properly, I'm referring the parameters [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates#parameters)

Comment: @jarrad_obrien Are you looking for this `copyIndex()` , for example, "name": "[concat('storage', copyIndex())]",  Creates these names: storage0 storage1 storage2 please refer to this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#resource-iteration